# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio missing

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm on Windows 7 (64 bit). I cannot figure out why Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio does not exist.

I can see the SQL Server running and also tried installing SQL client, but I had no success with that.

I desperately need help please.

Thanks

Comment: SSMS does not have to exist on the box to run. They are tools.

Comment: Run the installation program again and make sure to install the tools.

Comment: Did you install it? It has to be selected as one of the installed tools. (It's not automatically installed, because you wouldn't want it installed on the server itself in most cases; you'd install it on individual machines that access that server DB installation instead.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the installation Disk(s), you can install Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS) by going into **Add features to an existing instance of SQL Server 2008**

[See step by step guide here](http://nlpdotnet.com/Blog/2012/7/6.aspx) including screenshots.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks. After installing it, I ran it. I got a run-time error: Cannot create a stable subkey under a volatile parent key...then I clicked continue and tried to connect to localhost but git the error "A network-related or instance-specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible..." Any ideas?

Comment: my server tcp was using port 0 instead of 1433. What's wrong with MS!

Comment: @max LOL. Were you able to finally install it? Thanks for marking the answer if this was helpful.

Comment: yes, I was able to install it. I did turn on the compatibility setting for the executable but it probably does not matter despite the warning message. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In **SQL Server 2016** it has its own link:

[image]

Just download it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx